# Primary key composed

Tags: subsonic

```
Customer customer = new Cliente(4);
```

In the code an object customer is created locating through IdCliente  = 4

How would to create an object customer that possesses a primary key composed, to idEmpresa and idCliente?

Comment: Please edit your question and add more code and better examples. It's obvious English is not your primary language, so anything you can do to help us help you is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking if you can load an subsonic object that has a composite key.

```
Customer customer = new SubSonic.Select()
  .From(Customer.Schema)
  .Where(Customer.IdEmpresaColumn).IsEqualTo(idEmpresa)
  .And(Customer.IdClienteColumn).IsEqualTo(idCliente)
  .ExecuteSingle();
```

Please read http://subsonicproject.com/querying/select-queries/.